# how to include all polynomial and interaction terms

Tags: r, interaction

I have 50 predictors in my dataset, I would like to get the second order terms and the second order interaction terms of these predictors.

Take the mtcars data set in R base for an example:

```
> mtcars2=mtcars^2
> names(mtcars2)=paste0('sq_',names(mtcars2))
> mtcars3=cbind(mtcars,mtcars2)
> formula=paste0('mpg~',paste0(names(mtcars3[,2:22]),collapse='+'),collapse='+')
> fit=lm(formula,mtcars3)
> summary(fit)
```

I would like to get the two way interaction and polynomial terms of all predictors in the single model. Thank you very much.

Comment: Out of interest why would you ever want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost surely a bad idea. Anyway, using the mtcars data set, after removing categorical variables

```
mtcars=mtcars[,1:7]
lm(as.formula(paste0("mpg~.^2+",paste0("poly(",colnames(mtcars),",2)",collapse="+")))
,data=mtcars)
```

Comment: hi, thank you very much for the code, but why this is a bad idea? I was thinking to take the interaction and the quadratic effect into account. Are you worrying about the multicolinearity issue?

Comment: @user11806155 It has more to do with overfitting, model misspecification and use of polynomials.